# RouteUrl with querystring - with duplicate keys

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-mvc-routing

I use this extension to create an `RouteUrl` with the current query-string appended to it. This works fine for query-strings which does not have the same key twice or more.

```
public static string CurrentQueryStringRouteUrl(this UrlHelper url, string routeName, RouteValueDictionary routeValues)
{
    var context = url.RequestContext;
    var combinedRouteValues = new RouteValueDictionary();
    var queryString = context.HttpContext.Request.QueryString;

    foreach (var key in queryString.AllKeys.Where(key => key != null))
    {
        combinedRouteValues[key] = queryString[key];
    }

    if (routeValues != null)
    {
        foreach (var routeValue in routeValues)
        {
            combinedRouteValues[routeValue.Key] = routeValue.Value;
        }
    }

    return url.RouteUrl(routeName, combinedRouteValues);
}
```

When there is query-string keys of same name, e.g. `?id=1&id=2&id=3`, this is converted into `?id=1,2,3` using the method above. Is there any way to avoid that? I wish to keep the original query-string as I am binding these values on a model list.

I am aware I can create a custom model-binder to bind the comma separated string to `string[]` (or `int[]` in this example) but I wish to avoid this as far of consistence goes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can to do this, but it is dirty hack:

```
string _rawstring = context.HttpContext.Request.RawUrl;
int _f;
_f = _rawstring.IndexOf('?');
string _resultString = _rawstring.SubString(_f, _rawstring.Length);
```

Here you can find helpful info about that problem: [How to deal with more than one value per key in ASP.NET MVC 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6048218/how-to-deal-with-more-than-one-value-per-key-in-asp-net-mvc-3)

Comment: I just don't get why form POST and GET values is not combined as comma separated strings then. If I have a `select` element, with `multiple` set, the form submit result in `?id=1&id=2&id=3`

Comment: Try this: QueryString.AllKeys.InvalidateCachedArrays()

Comment: You get an array of non-cached keys.

Comment: I'll try it out on a few hours time, I return with how it go :-)

Comment: Thanks :-) WOrking on this in a few hours time and I see if I can get it to work :-)

Comment: I ended up creating a modelbinder for the string[].

Answer (score 0):

I took a slightly different approach, because I really needed separate duplicated keys in my query string.  I alter the key using a counter, and then after rendering the url string, I restore the original parameter names.  I needed this for GridMvc's `grid_filter` queries, but you can adapt it for your purpose.

```
/// <summary>
/// Allows you to create or extend a collection of route values to use in a url action
/// </summary>
public class RouteValueBuilder
{
    readonly RouteValueDictionary routeValues;
    private int gridFilterCounter = 0;

    public RouteValueBuilder(object existingRouteValues = null)
    {
        routeValues = existingRouteValues as RouteValueDictionary ?? new RouteValueDictionary(existingRouteValues);
    }

    public void Add(string field, object value)
    {
        if (field == "grid_filter" && routeValues.ContainsKey(field))
        {
            // Because we can't add duplicate keys and GridMvc doesn't support joined comma format for query strings,
            // we briefly rename each new filter, and then the Finalise method must be called after the url
            // string is rendered to restore the grid_filter names back to normal.
            gridFilterCounter++;
            routeValues.Add(field + gridFilterCounter, value);
        }
        else if (routeValues.ContainsKey(field))
        {
            // Since duplicate key names are not supported, the concatenated comma approach can be used
            routeValues[field] += "," + value;
        }
        else
        {
            routeValues.Add(field, value);
        }
    }

    public RouteValueDictionary Get()
    {
        return routeValues;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Cleans up the final string url, fixing workarounds done during the building process.
    /// This must be called after the final url string is rendered.
    /// </summary>
    public static string Finalise(string url)
    {
        // Restores grid_filter parameters to their correct naming.  See comments on Add method.
        for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            url = url.Replace("grid_filter" + i, "grid_filter");
        }

        return url;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
var builder = new RouteValueBuilder();
builder.Add("grid_filter", "value1");
builder.Add("grid_filter", "value2");
string url = Html.Action("Index", "Home", builder.Get());
url = RouteValueBuilder.Finalise(url);
```

Edit: Note that the comma concatenation approach actually doesn't work in the class because it gets encoded, but the support for duplication is the main taker from this example.